# How to make inner redirect for pages with url's which contains filenames not at end, but between slashes

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to make inner redirect in htacess for Apache 2.4.29 for urls like this:

- example.com/file.php/dir/dirnext
- example.com/dir/file.html/
- example.com/dir/dirnext/file.jpg/onemoredir/
- etc.

I mean if any filename appears in the url between two slashes -> redirect to 404 page. I try this, but it not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
```

Comment: `nginx` doesn't really support `mod_rewrite` or `.htaccess`

Comment: anubhava, i'm sorry - my mistake. Sever is apache 2.4.29

Comment: ok do you want this internal rewrite for anything that looks like file name such as `example.com/foo/xyz.123/bar` also even though `xyz.123` doesn't exist as file.

Comment: @anubhava, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+/ index.php?route=error/not_found [L,QSA]
```